# How to design bootstrap navbar dynamically?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navigation.php file, and a navigation.css. How can I synchronize them to work?

navigation.php:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" >
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php nav_main($dbc, $pageid); ?>
    </ul>       
  </div>
</nav>
```

navigation.css:

```
.navbar-custom {
  background-color:#229922;
  color:#ffffff;
  border-radius:0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navigation.css">` in your php file.

Comment: I 've tried it, but unfortunately havn't worked. My suspicion is around this line  <?php nav_main($dbc, $pageid); ?>  Any Idea?

Comment: @JustMatthew — What do you suspect? What do you expect to happen that doesn't happen? What don't you expect to happen that does?

Comment: LOL. Thx, rellay helpful :D Of course i want to costumize my navbar with css. Every tutorial i saw worked fine to everybody, but they didn't have php code in their nav class. That's why i was suspicius.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. The browser gets HTML. Look at the HTML the browser gets. Forget about the PHP unless you aren't generating the HTML you want to generate. What do you expect to happen that doesn't happen? What don't you expect to happen that does?

Comment: Ok, you win! I never expect nothing, and nowhere, except, I Iexpect you to except me to find a solution! Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score -1):

You have a navbar-custom class in your css file but dont use it in your html file

Comment: And how can i use it?

Comment: add navbar-custom to <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
so u have <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-custom">